# Using reference to "this" object from member variable

Tags: java

I am asked to say what does this code do but I really cannot figure it out.
I've tried to execute it in netbeans and got the answer `6` but really cannot understand why.

```
public class Quattro {
    int x = 5;
    Quattro s = this;
    Quattro f(){
        s.s.s.x++;
        return s;
    }
    void g(){System.out.println(x);}
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Quattro a4 = new Quattro();
        a4.f().g();
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** What does `Quattro s = this;` do? Am I declarind a pointer to my self? If so, it means that I can write

```
Quattro f(){
            s.s.s.x++;
            return s;
        }
```

or even

```
Quattro f(){
            s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.x++;
            return s;
        }
```

and I'll always get the same result because I'm in a loop?

**Question 2**: I do not understand what `a4.f().g();` does... seems so weird to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking 2 questions in a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign `this` reference to a member variable, you have a recursion. Yes, it doesn't matter how many `s`'s you'll add, because they are always the same object, which is `this` object. It's the same as if you wrote:

```
this.this.this.this.this.this.x++;
```

Function `f()` returns reference to `this` object after doing some other operations on it. It's a common design pattern in Java, called [builder](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm). Adding ability to do `a4.f().g();` to a class is called [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180314/5922757). In other words, `f()` is `this` object at the end of the call, just like `s` is, so you can do:

```
a1.f().f().f().f().f().f();
```

And it means you just called `f()` function from `a1` object 6 times.

Comment: Builder is a single use case of the pattern called Fluent API, and this code clearly isn't builder.

Comment: Well, it clearly **builds** `s` variable depending on how many times you call `f()`. [GsonBuilder](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) is a good example of a builder too. All this class lacks is the distinction between builder and object that is built. It's a builder that builds itself (;

Comment: Mutation is not building. You can't remove the essence of a concept and pretend it is still there.