# Purpose of "with" methods in class

Tags: java

I'm looking at class called Product which includes the following:

```
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Product withName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
```

what is the purpose of the withName method and how is it used? Why not just do:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.setName("foo");
```

Comment: Read about builder pattern

Comment: It allows [method chaing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The major difference is that the `with` method returns the instance of the object is called on.

That allows for "fluent" calls like

```
 someProductBuilder.withName("bla").withPrice(100)...
```

In that sense: an informal convention to *distinguish* ordinary setters from those that allow for fluent usage by returning the affected object.

Answer (score 1):

You could do either way, but the first is trying to provide a ["fluent" api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) so you can chain together a number of calls... something like:

```
Product p = new Product().withName("blah").price(1234).quantityOnHand(35);
```

It is similar to a builder where you may have another object that presents the api and then ends the chain with a "build()" call that produces the instance of the class you're building:

```
Product p = ProductBuilder.newBuilder().withName("blah").price(1234).quantityOnHand(35).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to get a reference to an object by its name so that method call can be chained with other calls on same object.

Example: [withName(String name)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/model/SecurityConfigurationSummary.html#withName-java.lang.String-)