# Generate chained setters

Tags: java, ide

I want to create a big Java object with 20 fields, most IDEs provide a generate function, which allows me to generate getters and setters for all the fields of my object.

The thing is, I am a big fan of [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java) and I am using it on all my objects, but I have to add `return this` at the end of each `setters`, which is not very handy.

Is it possible to generate setters with a special plugin form an IDE?

Comment: How would you chain getters?

Comment: My bad, edited.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You just blew my mind. But getters should probably not be chained (as they would serve no purpose otherwise).

Comment: FWIW, you should look into [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth while immutable DTOs/ValueObject are a very good idea *fluent API* on Builders is not that bad... ;o)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - Yeah, in this case, the fact that Immutables are immutable is less interesting than the fact that they give give you an autogenerated fluent builder API.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible in `IntelliJ IDEA`:

> 1. call "Generate > Setter" menu
> 2. select template "Builder".
> 3. Select all fields you want to generate setter
> 4. click 'Ok'.

Here is generated result (for 1 field):

```
public MyClass setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
        return this;
    }
```

It's also possible to create your own template there)

Answer (score 7):

You can try lombok

lombok.accessors.chain = [true | false] (default: false)

If set to true, generated setters will return this (instead of void). An explicitly configured chain parameter of an @Accessors annotation takes precedence over this setting.

Is this what you want ?
https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

public class LombokTest {
    private String test;

    public static void main(String []args) {
        LombokTest a = new LombokTest();
        System.out.println(a.setTest("amber").getTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use *lombok* with care! It changes the bytecode bypassing the JDKs compiler and you have to expect incompatibilities with future java versions.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally called "fluent" setters. There is [a plugin for Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55184/constants-fluent-setters-and-builder-generator) that does it automatically for you. I'm pretty sure you can find something equivalent in eclipse or IntelliJ.