# About Java grammar: Is it 'class.method.method'?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring framework with a tutorial online.
However, I have a question about this Java code:

```
     attributes.addFlashAttribute(ResultMessages.success().add(
             ResultMessage.fromText("Created successfully!")));
     return "redirect:/todo/list";
```

[Full source](http://terasolunaorg.github.io/guideline/5.3.0.RELEASE/en/Tutorial/TutorialTodo.html#id1)

What I'm wondering about: Is it 'Class.method.method'? If so, how can it be possible?

Comment: why do you think its not possible. can you be a bit explanatory?

Comment: If you ask this kind of question, you should not use Spring yet. Please learn the Java basics and look at the soure code of Spring.

Comment: I think that we can't define a method in another method.

Comment: And where do you see a method defined in another?

Comment: @LCL , you are not defining a method, you are calling on. not on the method itself, but on what it returns. just take a look at the answer I've posted, it gives an example of what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to achieve method chaining in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java)

Comment: Thank you all! I've got the concept!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called method chaining or named parameter idiom and it is a syntax for invoking multiple method calls. This is a common feature on many object oriented languages.

Simply speaking, by this syntax you directly invoke a method on the returned value without the need of assignment to a variable object first. One major advantage is the reduction of vertical problem in programming.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is the simplest and the most understandable :)

Answer (score 7):

It's called chaining. the second method is called upon the returned value of the first.

let's say this:

```
public Person {
  private String name;
  public Person(String name){ this.name = name; }

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

if you have an instance p of Person, the next two snippets are the same (in result)

```
String pN = p.getName().toUpperCase();
```

and:

```
   String name = p.getName();
   String pN = name.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: @Berger nice catch ;)

Comment: And chaining can also be done with array indexing: `name.toUpperCase().toCharArray()[0].toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a perfect example :D