# How can I call the method after another method?

Tags: java, android, methods

I want to develop a library with a new idea for Android applications but I have problem. How can I call the method after another method?

for example...

```
Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

my codes

MyClass class

```
public class MyClass {

    public static MyClass A(){
        return A();
    }

    public static void show(){

    }
```

MainActivity Class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //It's normal
    MyClass.A();
    //if he wrote like this I want tell him error
    MyClass.show();
    //I want like this
    MyClass.A().show();

}
```

Comment: You do just what you did there-  chain them if allowed.  Or write a function that calls A() then B().  If you mean something more than that, you need to be much more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Do you means you wants to know what your first method should return in order to call the 2nd one? If that's it, the answer is: Any kind of object that has method. You question is way to broad

Comment: I only want to show the method after calling a particular method , but if he wrote Toast.show(); do not show.

Comment: @jhamon yes I want that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java ? You can only do `thing.a().b().c()` if `thing.a()` returns some object with a `b()` method, and then that `b()` method then returns an object with a `c()` method, etc. `thing.a().b()` is equivalent to `BThing bt = thing.a(); bt.b()` without making `bt` a visible variable in the code.

Comment: `public static MyClass A(){ return A(); }` This will cause a StackOverflowError..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a litte hard to understand what you want, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
public class Toast {
    private String text = null;

    public Toast makeText(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
        return this;
    }

    public void show() {
        if (text == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Text must be set before you can call show.");
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Toast toast = new Toast();
        toast.makeText("test").show();

        final Toast toastError = new Toast();
        toastError.show();
    }
}
```

By returning the instance of the object in the makeText-method you can call show afterwards.

Comment: *maybe this is what you are looking for* - let's not post guesses as answers. Ask for clarification if you are unsure

Comment: yes I want like this but I want if he wrote myClass.show(); tell him error

Comment: @TahaSami updated the answer to throw an exception if text is not set.

Comment: @knutesten Is there a way to make it appear only after use makeText method ?

Comment: @TahaSami I did not understand you question. What should only appear after calling makeText?

Comment: @TahaSami You dont want the show-method to exist before makeText is called?

Comment: It's working now thank you very mush

Comment: @knutesten yes I want this :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is irrelevant.  
What is important is the way classes and methods work in Java.
Since you declare `show()` as `static` then the only way to call it is:

```
MyClass.show();
```

If you remove static keyword then you can do this:

```
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   myClass.show();
```

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: @jhamon OP asks how can he call show after he creates the toast, did you read?

Comment: you should call up show method after makeText() method but you can't use Toast.show(). , This is what I want the method to call only after calling a particular method in my library

Comment: @TahaSami This is what this code does. It prepares the Toast and shows it when you need it.

Comment: @TahaSami see my edited answer

Comment: This is an example, but I have my library , for example I have Color class inside class there  2 methods A(); show(); I if I wrote Color.A(); will showing and if I wrote Color.show(); will showing but I want if he wrote Color.show(); now showing but if he wrote Color.A() so show will showing like this , Color.A().show();

Comment: Post your code so we can stop guessing what you want

Comment: @TahaSami If you want to get help you must phrase clearly your problem. At this case you are not. Edit your question with beter phrasing and the needed code.

Comment: Well I will change my participation Wait 5 minutes

Comment: Modified  you can see now

Comment: @TahaSami So what did all this have to do with Toast?

Comment: The problem was resolved at the top , thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you want it, but maybe something like this:

```
static class MyClass{
  private static MyClass instance;

  public static MyClass A(){
    if(instance == null){
      instance = new MyClass();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public void show(){
    // TODO: Do something
  }
}
```

And you can now call it like this:

```
MyClass.A().show();
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##XZC9DoIwFIV3nuKGqQzyABIG/@LkRJyMQ4WqxVIIbSHE8Oy10CLKdJNzz/l6T3Pc4FWevbSu1I3RFFKGhYATpvztAQiJ5Sx2u2EOOkBV0wZLMjncDig3Ak9JNJqs04IXxg0KLAiA3tEUgzgGrhj77gDmFXDSTnkURM7Ru1kTqWq@OKD3fk9oSpqBeJbt/HbSCUmKsFQyNI24ZBz5@8P2fFw7ox9MJEf7rzMiC/NbKJEm/7hcATu4uzQ0TUPLikZGr/UH)

`MyClass` is now a [Singleton](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples), which only has a single instance alive. I would advice renaming `MyClass` to `MySingleton` and `A()` to `getInstance()`. *(Also, if you're using it in multiple threads and want to make it thread-safe, you can add the `synchronized` keyword to the method. But I guess it's single-threaded considering you use it in your Android Activity class, which uses the default UI-thread.)*