# Java method().method().method(); How to do this?

Tags: java, method-chaining

For example how do I do this?

```
getServer().getManager().registerNewUser(arguments);
```

and

```
getServer().getStats().user(arguments);
```

Stuff like this, I've tried searching the web but I cant find any tutorials on this,so I'm asking here.

Comment: The previous has to return an object on which you can call the next method, `getServer()` might return a `Server` instance, that has a `getManager()` methid

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java

Comment: Thanks <3, yes this is it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In OOP, in general, this concept is called class composition more on this you can find it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Also for java and the difference between Composition and inheritance https://www.baeldung.com/java-inheritance-composition

Comment: It's called method chaining.

Comment: getServer() returns an object called server getStats() returns and obejct called Stats. he's probably asking about composition in OOP