# Fluent Interface in Spring Boot Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, fluent, method-chaining

I am building a Spring Boot project for work.
In this project I have service which is tasked with getting certain Documents from another backend. There a quite a lot of different scenarios where the documents have to meet certain criteria e.g. be from a certain date, which can be matched freely. Currently this is accomplished with normal method like so:

```java
@Service
public class DocumentService(){

  private OtherService otherService;

  @Autowire
  public DocumentService(OtherService otherService){
    this.otherService = otherService;
  }

  public List<Document> getDocuments() {
   ...
  }

  public List<Document> getDocuments(LocalDate date) {
   ...
  }

  public List<Document> getDocuments(String name){
   ...
  }

  public List<Document> getDocuments(String name, LocalDate date){
   ...
  }

}
```

I find this to be a rather bad solution because for every new combination there would need to be a new method.
For that reason I'd like to use a fluent style interface for that, something like this:

```java
//Some other class that uses DocumentService
documentService().getDocuments().withDate(LocalDate date).withName(String name).get();
```

I'm familiar with [the Builder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) and [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java) but I don't see a way how I can adapt either one of those. Seeing as, per my understanding, @Service-classes are singletons in Spring Boot.

Is this at all possible with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't have to be a Spring Boot solution, why not just introduce a POJO builder-like local class:

```java
@Service
public class DocumentService(){
    public Builder documents() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public class Builder {
        private LocalDate date;
        private String name;

        public Builder withDate(LocalDate date) {
            this.date = date;
            return this;
        }

        // etc

        public List<String> get() {
            final List<SomeDTO> results = otherService.doQuery(name, date, ...);
            // TODO - tranform DTO to List<String>
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously make it static if it doesn't need access to the parent component.

You *could* make the Spring component and the builder be the same object but that does feel contrived, also I expect you would like to be able to support multiple builders.

Also I'm assuming the parent component is genuinely a service, i.e. it doesn't contain any state or mutators, otherwise you are introducing potential synchronization problems.

EDIT: Just for illustration the builder maintains the arguments to be passed to the `otherService` and performs any service-like transforms.

Comment: The parent component does not have any state or such but it references other components, see the code example I've updated. Would this also pose a problem?

Comment: Don't see that as a problem no, the only reason I mentioned is that the service is a singleton so you need to be aware of such considerations, but of course that applies to all your components (I shouldn't have confused the matter!)

Comment: Could you also elaborate a little more on the builder? The Arguments are supposed to go inside the builder class, correct? Also should I just do the logic inside the `.get()` function or pass the builder to the @Service class? Thanks for clarifying the part before :)

Comment: @Puck Yes the arguments are properties of the builder.  I've added a little bit more illustration, the `otherService` is treated as a DAO or spring data resource (just for example purposes), and the get() method does some transform of the results which is often required in a service.  Hope that helps.  You'll probably need to consider validation of the arguments before delegating to collaborating components.

Comment: Thanks alot, that will do. I've marked you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a fluent interface here, the object returned by your `getDocuments()` method would have to be the starting point for the method chain.  Perhaps create something like a `DocumentFilter` class that you can return from there, then you'll end up with something like this:

```
documentService.documents().getDocuments().withDate(LocalDate date).withName(String name).getDocuments()
```

In this example, your `DocumentFilter` will have `withDate(...)` and `withName(...)` methods, and each subsequent call includes all of the criteria from the preceding `DocumentFilter`.