# Declare a method to return this (java)

Tags: java

It is easy to define a method returning the same value as the argument:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Derived sth = new Derived();
        String x = sth.foo("hello");
        System.out.println(x);
        Derived resultTypeIsKnown = sth.foo(sth);  // <==== !!!
        System.out.println(""+resultTypeIsKnown);
    }
}
class Base {
    <T>T foo(T t)
    {
        return t;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
}
```

You see that the compiler knows that although `foo()` is declared in the `Base` class, the compiler knows that `sth.foo(sth)` returns an instance of the `Derived` class:

```
Derived derivedRatherThanBase = sth.foo(sth);
```

***How do I declare that the return value is of the same class as the object whose method is called?*** (In particular, for a method that always returns `this`?)

Something like:

```
class Base {
    <?ThisClass?> bar() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I can write

```
    <T>T getThis(T t)
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
```

but `x.getThis(x)` uses an extra argument and produces a warning.

**UPDATE** OMG, what they are doing in the "possible duplicate"... But I already have the base class, it's a descendant of `Collection`. In other words, it is required that `class Base extends Collection` *and* knows its class.

And the real life code where I want to know `THISCLASS` already is very complex.

**UPDATE2** As to the XY problem, what I want is:

```
class MyVerySpecialCollectionBase extends ... {
    ...
    THISCLASS addAll(Collection items) { ... }
}
class MyExtendedVerySpecialCollection extends MyVerySpecialCollectionBase  {
    ...
}

// use: 
MyExtendedVerySpecialCollection x =
      new MyExtendedVerySpecialCollection(aLotOfArgs)
      .addAll(list1)
      .addAll(list2);
```

The proposed solution sounds too complex and even less acceptable than either (1) redefining addAll() in each derived class or (2) making `x.addAll(list1).addAll(list2);` a separate statement.

Comment: It's a useless construct since the static type system cannot enforce it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OOP in Java: Class inheritance with method chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054237/oop-in-java-class-inheritance-with-method-chaining)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to do such a thing ??