# How driver.navigate().to() work on selenium in Selenium class? Means what is navigate() and to()?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am confused with this. Basically when we create an object of a class, then we can access `property` or `method`. Up to I am fine. But what when we are creating an object of `WebDriver` class in `Selenium` and setting URL through `driver.navigate().to()`. So Why are here two things `navigate()` and `to()` after the Selenium object `driver`.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180269/how-to-achieve-method-chaining-in-java

Comment: @Asraful Haque, should I add more explanation to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Navigate is an interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Navigation.html) to navigate through the browser:

Navigate is a way of interacting with the browser.

The method `.to()` is a function of the interface to get a URL.

The shorter way to do `driver.navigate().to()` is `driver.get()`

With `navigate` you have more methods like: `driver.navigate().forward();`
and `driver.navigate().back();`

Hope this helps you!

PS:

As @muraliselenium has commented if your question is about "method chaining" you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15054237/8179099)

Comment: @AsrafulHaque glad to be of help! happy holydays!